# Get subclass from Generic method in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, abstract

I'm trying to write a curious method:

```
Map<Class, AbstractTool> ToolMap = new HashMap<Class, AbstractTool>();
//init'd correctly

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends AbstractTool> T getTool(Class cls){
    if (ToolMap.containsKey(cls)) {
        return (T) ToolMap.get(cls);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

In a weird twist of events, this code actually does what I need it to do. My main issue is the fact that in order to call it, i have to make these big calls:

```
this.getTool<ToolType>(ToolType.class);
```

Not Cool.

---

Is there a way to write this method so that it has the following signature?:

```
ToolType t = this.getTool<ToolType>();
```

or this one

```
ToolType t = this.getTool(ToolType); // This one seems impossible without casting.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one won't work because you're looking up a type at runtime, so that parameter is gone.  The second one works fine if you just fix your method declaration.  `Class` is a parameterized type that you declared raw.

If you do:

```
 Map<Class<? extends AbstractTool>, AbstractTool> ToolMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractTool>, AbstractTool>();

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T extends AbstractTool> T getTool(Class<T> cls){
    if (ToolMap.containsKey(cls)) {
        return (T) ToolMap.get(cls);
    }
    else return null;
  }
```

Then you can do:

```
ToolType t = this.getTool(ToolType.class);
```

Comment: And since you have `cls`, it's probably worth using it to make a checked cast which will get rid of the warning (`return cls.cast(ToolMap.get(cls))`)

Comment: Thank you kindly. Even though C# and java are quite similar, these little minutia always get me.